# best practice for Django junction table model structure

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using a junction table called "UserRole" for 2 different Django model called CustomUser and Role to specify many to many relationship from both of the table. My consideration is 1 customer can have multiple groups and 1 groups has multiple customers. So now I am little confused that my current model is OK or Do I need to modify

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    """Model representing a User with some extended fields and email as username field"""
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField('Permission', related_name='+')
    # other fields goes here if needed
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    
    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.email

class Role(models.Model):
    """Model representing a Role"""
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # other fields goes here if needed
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.name

class UserRole(models.Model):
    """Model representing a User's Role"""
    
    # ManyToManyField used because one user can have multiple roles and one role can have multiple users
    role_id = models.ManyToManyField(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,  verbose_name = 'Role', related_name='role')
    user_id = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,  verbose_name = 'User', related_name='user_role')
    # other fields goes here if needed
```

**So my question is, the relationship is ok as I stated below?**

```
role_id = models.ManyToManyField(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,  verbose_name = 'Role', related_name='role')
user_id = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,  verbose_name = 'User', related_name='user_role')
```

**OR**

```
role_id = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,  verbose_name = 'Role', related_name='role')
user_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False,  verbose_name = 'User', related_name='user_role')
```

Comment: No, what you do is making 3 extra tables, when you only need one, you should simply use `ForeignKey`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it makes no sense to work with `ManyToManyField`s, your `UserRole` is the junction table between the `CustomUser` and the `Role`. If two `CustomUser`s have the same role, you thus create two `UserRole` records.

The junction table thus has two `ForeignKey`s: one to the user model, and one to the `Role` and there can be additional fields.

You can also specify a `ManyToManyField` from `CustomUser` to `Role` or vice versa, where you can specify `UserRole` as the [**`through=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

You can thus implement this as:

```
from django.conf import settings

class CustomUser(models.Model):
    # …

class Role(models.Model):
    # …
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='roles',
        through='UserRole'
    )

class UserRole(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(
        Role,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name = 'role',
        related_name='user_roles'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name = 'user',
        related_name='user_roles'
    )
    # …
```

Here we thus can for a given `Role` obtain the `CustomUser`s for that role with:

```
my_role.members.all()
```

or all the `Role`s for a given user:

```
my_user.roles.all()
```

You can also obtain all the related `UserRole`s of a given user or `Role` with:

```
my_role.user_roles.all()
my_user.user_roles.all()
```

these `UserRole` objects that contain references to the `User` and the `Role` together with  (possibly) extra data, for example when the `CustomUser` was assigned that `Role`.